# It seems Swfit.AnyHashable is not casing (as!, as?, as) properly with enums

Tags: swift, enums, hashable

Here is a simple case example of AnyHashable not supporting casting with enums.

```
enum testEnum: String {
    case Test
}

let myObject: AnyHashable = testEnum.Test as AnyHashable
let newObject = myObject as? testEnum
```

In this case newObject will return nil. If I cast instead do

```
let newObject = (myObject as? AnyObject) as? testEnum
```

it will cast fine.

I have tried this with structs, custom classes and String and they all cast properly. For instance this works.

```
let myObject: AnyHashable = "Test" as AnyHashable
let newObject = myObject as? String
```

Is this a bug in swift or am I just not doing this correctly here.

I tried this in Swift 3.2 and Swift 4.

Comment: You should use `Any` instead of `AnyHashable`. btw it is Swift convention to name your enum starting with an uppercase letter and your cases starting with a lowercase letter

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`AnyHashable` [explicitly type-erases](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/anyhashable#):

> The AnyHashable type forwards equality comparisons and hashing operations to an underlying hashable value, hiding its specific underlying type.

The fact that this happens to work for some types is the surprising fact, not that it fails for enums. I would expect it's a performance optimization to help with dictionaries. But this isn't how you're expected to use `AnyHashable`. The expected usage is to initialize it with `AnyHashable.init`, not `as AnyHashable`.

What you meant is this:

```
enum TestEnum: String {
    case test
}

let myObject = AnyHashable(TestEnum.test)
myObject.base               // => test (as an Any)
myObject.base as? TestEnum  // => Optional<TestEnum>(.test)
```

Note that `AnyHashable` is a completely different kind of thing than `Any` or `AnyObject`. The latter two are protocols. The former is a type-erasing struct. The prefix `Any...` in the stdlib means "type-eraser" except for the oddball special-cases (that you should avoid as much as humanly possible) `Any` and `AnyObject`.

Comment: I know that AnyHashable is just a wrapper to erase the type which is why I was using it. But I guess the inconsistent behavior threw me off. I assumed it had some shorthand support to ignore the base property for ease of use based on the fact it worked for some types (well any type except enum).